# How to remove the Username field from the UserCreationForm in Django

Tags: django, forms, django-registration

I want my user registration page to display email and password field, and no username.
I have created this Register Form:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    #fullname = forms.CharField(label = "First name")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", )

    def save(self, commit=True):        
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
           user.save()
        return user
```

But the username still appears. Do I need to override something else?

Comment: I think username field come from `UserCreationForm`, so `exclude` it from there!

Answer (score 8):

You can pop out the username from the form's fields like so:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        # remove username
        self.fields.pop('username')
    ...
```

But then you would need to fill-in some random username before saving like so:

```
from random import choice
from string import letters
...

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
...
    def save(self):
        random = ''.join([choice(letters) for i in xrange(30)])
        self.instance.username = random
        return super(RegisterForm, self).save()
```

There are other considerations to take when you hack it this way, like making sure your LoginForm would pull the username later on when it is needed:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"), max_length=75)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['email'].required = True 
        # remove username
        self.fields.pop('username')

    def clean(self):
        user = User.objects.get(email=self.cleaned_data.get('email'))
        self.cleaned_data['username'] = user.username
        return super(LoginForm, self).clean()
```

Comment: Sorry, the LoginForm with the email field will show password first and then email. Put this inside __init__ to fix that:      self.fields.keyOrder = ['email','password',]

Answer (score 1):

Found it. This is exactly what I wanted to do:
http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html

Comment: that's INTERNET for you. I should have pasted the content of the website here. Now I don't even work with django anymore. Sorry my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Add that field to the Meta class's exclude:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Email")
    #fullname = forms.CharField(label = "First name")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ['username',]
```

Comment: That didn't help really. so I tried different variations of that exclude but it didn't work for me.